# Convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyymmdd (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Is there any way I can convert a date of format: dd/mm/yyyy to yyyymmdd format? For example from : 25/07/2011 to 20110725? in VB.NET?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dates themselves don't *have* formats inherently. You can parse a string into a `DateTime` by parsing it with `dd/MM/yyyy` format and then convert that into a string using `yyyyMMdd` format:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string reformatted = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or in VB:

```
Dim date as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim reformatted as String = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

(And make sure you have an import for `System.Globalization`.)

However, ideally you should keep it as a `DateTime` (or similar) for as long as possible.

Comment: Jon, Just curious about this one. Why can't he use `String.Format` method?

Comment: @reggie: For the second line? He could, but it would be more work IMO. Why specify a compound string format specifier when you only want to format a single value?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the second line is what I missed!

Comment: I'm not at all accomplished in vb.net, so please don't take this as a criticism because it is just a question..could be something I'm missing.  I understand a little bit about what the whole Culture piece refers to from a semantic standpoint, but from a syntactical standpoint it appears to be completely ... Not accepted, when I try to type it into the SSIS IDE for .net.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Isaac: I don't know anything about the SSIS IDE, but the original answer was only in C#, not VB. I've provided a VB version as well now. Make sure you've imported the `System.Globalization` namespace.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  I was sort of thinking that.  Thank you

Answer (score 7):

```
 CDate(Datetext).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: This answer could fail depending on the culture. That's why Jon's answer is better than this one. For example, how would decide if 10/12/2017 is 10th December or 12th October without the ParseExact?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method to parse the date, then use `DateTimeObj.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`.

[DaTeTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Public Function DateFormateYYYYMMDD(ByVal Dtp As DateTimePicker) As String

   Try
      Dim StrDate, StrYear, StrMonth, StrDay As String
      StrDate = FormatDateTime(Dtp.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)
      StrMonth = Month(Dtp.Value)
      StrDay = Convert.ToString(Dtp.Value.Day)
      StrYear = Year(Dtp.Value)
      StrDate = StrYear + "-" + StrMonth + "-" + StrDay

      Return StrDate
   Catch ex As Exception

   End Try
End Function
```

this function can be used to convert datetime picker value format to yyyyMMdd