# Formatting DateTime with another format

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

Assume I have start_date. Format saved in database is "2014-07-16 23:30:00". At my program, I have retrieve the data. My PC datetime format is "7/16/2014 11:30PM".

Question: How do I gonna do to convert from datetime to another datetime format? I want it to be 16-07-2014 11:30PM. Any ways?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858895/convert-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyymmdd-vb-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert date format in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755940/how-to-convert-date-format-in-vb-net)

Comment: What database are you using and what is the data type for the column that stores the date?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim dt As DateTime
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDateTimestring, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Nothing)

Dim result As String
result = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt")
```

This will give output in the format of "16-07-2014 11:30PM"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in VB.NET:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Nothing).ToString("M\/d\/yyyy hh:mmtt")
```

Comment: still having exception. The 7/16/2014 11:30PM cannot change to 16-07-2014 11:30PM format.

Comment: if input is '7/16/2014 11:30PM', you can use: DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M\/d\/yyyy hh:mmtt", Nothing).ToString("M\/d\/yyyy hh:mmtt")